# Possible requirejs waitSeconds per filepath?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn

Is it possible to set the waitSeconds to per filepath?  I'd like to set it low for CDN requests with fallbacks to load the local file from disk.  This would be helpful to not be slow if a CDN is having trouble or latency to the CDN is high.  This should allow my setup to be more reliable when using CDNs.

According to jburke, creator of requirejs, this is not possible and will not be added:

> This is not possible to do today, no plans to add it. Closing, but
>   feel free to continue discussion here.

Comment: See related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599082/poll-for-resource-available-with-requirejs/18364009#18364009 You might be able to simulate something like this by setting the waitSeconds very low for all but then using retry logic on certain paths